# Strongest material made of baryonic matter

Tags: material-science

What is the upper limit to the strength of a material made of baryonic (e.g. 'normal') matter? Researchers are discovering new and stronger materials every year but is there a limit that they will reach before they cannot make another material that is stronger? There are some very impressive achievements out there, such as graphene, but I believe it is possible to make even stronger materials.

(I mean strength as in the best combination of melting point, hardness, yield strength, tensile strength, toughness, and stiffness)

P.S. Also, no 'exotic' material would fit the bill, such as in neutron stars or quark stars.

Comment: The answer will depend on clarifying the question.  This article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials will help define what type of strength is being asked about.

Comment: Hi Hami Hashmi. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Oh ok. On my original question, it said i can either edit the question or post a new one, but i will do what you said. Thanks

Comment: Here is an answer to a related question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/525827/37364. For strong materials and materials with high melting/boiling points, atoms must stick together strongly.